# Subtraction of one list of lists from another list of lists

Tags: python, list

I want to subtract a list of lists from corresponding elements of another list of lists such as:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[1, 2], [3, 0]]
```

with expected output to be:

```
c = [[0, 0], [0, 4]]
```

Subtraction with only one list from another is easy with:

```
c = [i - j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

but this isn't working for a list of lists and returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried nested loops to extract the items and build the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
c = [list(map(lambda x, y: x - y, ii, jj)) for ii, jj in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Cool, glad this could help. Although the `numpy`-based solution below works nicely, it still should require importing an external module and conversion from `numpy.array` to `list`, even if implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

use numpy arrays

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> b=np.array([[1,2],[3,0]])
>>> a-b
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension where the inner one performs subtraction for each pair of lists:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[1, 2], [3, 0]]
c = [[ii - jj for ii, jj in zip(i, j)] 
     for i, j in zip(a, b)]
print(c)
#  [[0, 0], [0, 4]]
```